# Which heroes can clear this jump on Volskaya Industries?

Tags: overwatch

On the Attackers first stage spawn there is a side route that seems to be reachable by some heroes but not all that stretches over the frozen river on the left.

[image]

[image: The jump.]

I've tested this with easier mobility heroes, like D.va, and Pharah, who can both clear the jump. However, I've tried testing Genji and Tracer, and I can't seem to get across as easily or consistently, or in some cases just plain unable to, like with Hanzo and Widowmaker, who I'm not sure can clear the jump are not.

Which heroes can make this jump, and how so?

Comment: Can't you just run around a few feet to the right?

Comment: @GnomeSlice You could, then get focus slaughtered by a camping Bastion, a McCree waiting around the corner, a turret set up by a Torbjorn on the truck, and a nice batch of Symm sentries to slow you down before you can even get past the sign.

Comment: Downvoted within minutes again.  Must be a "misunderstanding" I guess

Comment: @Retrosaur I think this was a great question! I wish I knew the answer myself, maybe I'll go do some researching/testing to figure it out!

Comment: @RainMaker I look forward to an answer from you :)

Comment: For clarification, do you mean the curved section of wall in the foreground, or the jump to the little covered outcropping in the background?

Comment: @Fluttershy The orange building that juts out to the left ini the picture, there's this wide gap of water that instakills you if you fall in it, that's the jump I'm curious about.

Comment: +1 I think downvoters misunderstand the question.  He is talking about the jump around the left side of the big red building, not the jump across the little curved section of the pond.  The former is very relevant to the strategy on the map, while the latter is useless trivia.

Comment: The original screenshot puts the focus on entirely the wrong jump, with a thin, low-contrast arrow that's barely visible. I've suggested an edit with an image based on the answer's screenshot; if there's something wrong with the new image, feel free to reject or revert the edit.

Comment: @user2357112 That is a fair point, but I felt a screenshot too close would confuse viewers as to where exactly the jump was, so I wanted to put in terms of how you would see it as you exited Attackers spawn.

Comment: @Retrosaur I can tell you why you get down-votes, but you're not gona like it (ps, it wasn't me that gave you a down-vote when you've noticed it.

Comment: I like this question a lot because I never knew this route existed and oh my god, this map totally needed another way in to the Point A objective. Hope to see more questions like this for other maps.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Alright, after some rough science, I know for a fact the following heroes can reach that outcropping:

**Genji** - The trick with Genji is to jump out as close to the wall as possible. From there, turning and wall running up that wall will give you some additional height. From here, it's possible to use his second jump, and his Swift Strike to reach the ledge.

**Pharah** - This one's pretty self explanatory. Reserved use of her Hover will get you to the platform. If you feel you need additional height, you can use her Jump Jets so you have some more leeway in your travel. Additionally, you can use her Concussive Blast to give you an added push toward the outcrop before hovering onto it.

**Reaper** - Can simply teleport to the outcropping. Probably the easiest of the group to get there.

**Tracer** - If you jump off the ledge from fairly close to the corner, it is possible to use all *three* of her Blinks to reach the ledge, but the timing can be tricky.

**D.Va** - So, I may have been wrong about Reaper being the easiest. D.Va can simply use her Boosters to reach the ledge, but you want to be somewhat close to the corner of the starting point due to the short duration of the skill.

**Winston** - This was probably the hardest one for me to get. I failed 4 out of 5 times before finally succeeding. The trick here is to get a running start, angled more toward the outcropping like so:

[image: Winston braves the icy waters below]

From here, it is possible, *but quite difficult*, to use his Jump Pack to reach the outcropping. With practice, I could see it being quite useful, as it gives you almost direct access to areas I normally see a Widowmaker or Bastion set up.

**Lucio** - Lucio is able to use his Wall Ride to reach the outcropping, but the last jump off the wall and into the space can be difficult if you aren't handy with his Wall Ride (I wasn't, but I managed to make it work). His Speed Boost helps get you there *faster*, but it's still possible to make it without the Speed Boost active.

**Mercy** - I wasn't able to test this myself, as I hopped in the match solo to try the other heroes, but the comments below confirm that Mercy can make it if she has someone on the outcropping to whom she could Glide.

**Widowmaker** - I came close a number of times. Tauntingly close, even. Her hook would grab the ledge, and I would start to be pulled to it, but my pinky toe would touch the water, killing me instantly. However, [Sepia's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269432/which-heroes-can-clear-this-jump-on-volskaya-industries/269455#269455) shows that yes, she can make it.

**Junkrat** - Per the comments and Sepia's answer, Junkrat can make it with careful use of his Concussion Mine. I wasn't able to get it to work, but I will be the first to admit I am terrible at maneuvering with his mines.

**Sombra** - With her Translocator, it's possible for her to clear this gap as well. You just have to aim high so the Translocator hits the edge of the platform on its downward arc.

**Symmetra** - With her rework, Symmetra and her teammates can clear this gap together.

Unfortunately, no other heroes were able to make it to the ledge. I tried with everyone who I thought *might* stand a chance, but that still leaves nearly two-thirds of the available heroes behind to risk the choke point.

Comment: Wow, thanks for really testing this out for me. In a few days I will be putting out a bounty, thanks a lot; I'm going to have to practice this as much as possible.

Comment: I'll try and find out for sure whether or not Widowmaker and Mercy can make it with help, but it may be a day or two before I can give it a try. If/when I do, I'll update accordingly.

Comment: @Fluttershy Amazing Answer! I was just about to get on this when I was reviewing the question and saw you had already done an amazing job!

Comment: Great answer, @Fluttershy - You can add Mercy for sure, just jump and try to grab your teammate when he reach the other side, or during his landing. I did it on a Pharah one time and I think the player got insecure and shift up in the building, I did land safe but she felt into the water.
The trick with Mercy is the distance, too close you don't get momentum and too far you lose the reach of your flight. It's the same in the left(attackers) stairs on the B point. Saw several Junkrat miss miserably there.

Comment: Btw: Junkrat- you can get a good horizontal boost with him, but to land safe without pixel management I suggest a Lucio on your team with speed bost on. Need test that, but I did some great stunts with him+Lucio in Nepal to be confident on that.

Comment: I can confirm it's possible with Widowmaker, without any help.  You don't need to jump off the edge, just peek around the corner and grab the nearest end of the ledge.  Also Winston is pretty easy if you jump first, _then_ use his ability in the air.

Comment: For junkrat, did you try his double jump? I.e. throw down a concussion mine, wait for it to be off cooldown, detonate, and throw another while airborne from the first mine

Comment: Mercy would definitely work, if you get her ability to lock on someone standing there (or simply following someone who just jumped).

Comment: Video evidence of Widowmaker making that jump. https://youtu.be/iRYyq1Fw9e0?t=1m30s

Comment: @Sumurai8 The problem I have with that jump is if you hit the ledge too high then you fly into the wall and are unable to land when you go down, or if you go too low, then as Flutter mentions your feet dips the water and you die before you can have enough momentum to get back up.

Comment: Can Moira make it with her *blink* ability?

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the heroes [confirmed by Fluttershy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269432/which-heroes-can-clear-this-jump-on-volskaya-industries/269445#269445):

It is possible with Junkrat in the manner [given by Cyoce](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269432/which-heroes-can-clear-this-jump-on-volskaya-industries/269445#comment377223_269445): "throw down a concussion mine, wait for it to be off cooldown, detonate, and throw another while airborne from the first mine". The second mine can be thrown when over halfway to propel yourself over the roof and into the courtyard.

It is possible with Widowmaker by using the grappling hook very early.

The video also contains the jump being performed by most of the other characters mentioned, starting from 1:57.

Comment: The description you give seems a bit vague. Please take in account that, while it's OK to provide an answer that suppliments another, it shouldn't need the other answer _nor_ external videos to stand on its own. When it comes to videos, linking them is always good, but you should write the answer detailed enough that it is still usable, even if the video gets taken down.

Comment: @DJPirtu I've added a little more explanation. If you think this answer is still not useful on its own I can delete it and either submit as a comment or a proposed edit on Fluttershy's answer.

Comment: No need to go as far as deletion. My suggestion are just to make sure your answer remains useful enven if the videos and the other answers happen to get deleted. Shouldn't happen, but you know, just in case.

Comment: Ah, excellent! I came very, very close with Widowmaker and Junkrat, but I could never get it to work. It's nice to see my efforts weren't in vain, and that it *is* possible.

Comment: @Fluttershy: Widowmaker is as easy as Reaper, just grapple _without_ jumping off the ledge.