# How to beat organised turret defenses?

Tags: overwatch

Recently I've noticed a severe increase in compositions consisting of one Torbjorn and on Symmetra, particularily on Volksaya Industries. (Usually a D.Va too).

When queuing with 2 friends and 3 randoms, this poses a difficult problem, as there are very few setups that can reliably dismantle this defense- *especially* when the enemy team is clearly using voice chat.

What kind of compositions can take on this setup (with the turret initially placed in the defending side building that opens onto the point (Red/A on diagram), then moving the turret to the little bunker facing away from the attacking spawn when the flankers start to adapt(Orange/B on diagram))? Snipers and Pharah struggle to pip the turret because of the range, and are incredibly vulnerable to Orb of Discord, and Winston gets shredded by the big turret as he melts the little ones.

This is the setup I'm talking about. There are very few flank routes that can allow you to safely take out these positions without exposing yourself to covering fire or the enemy team.

[image: Volskaya turret placements]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to counter a team of multiple Torbjörns?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271077/how-to-counter-a-team-of-multiple-torbj%c3%b6rns)

Comment: I don't consider this a duplicate- I'm asking specifically about a 1 Torbjorn, 1 Symmetra team, not 2 Torbjorns.

Comment: It's 99% the same question, with 100% the same answer.  I stand by my vote.

Comment: That question is about mutliple turrets with no mention of organisation. A setup like that can be broken by less people because the enemy team is not communicating. My question asks how do deal with a similar setup when the enemy is clearly communicating (you kill a turret and a d.va + junkrat immediately appear to wipe you out). It may have a similar answer, but I'm not asking the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My favorite hero to play against multiple turrets is Junkrat. He can launch his grenades into hard to get to places and deal quite a lot of AOE damage to help push a Torbjörn off from repairing his turret and to destroy it. He can bounce them off walls into room where turrets are setup, or launch them far enough to hit the turret over a wall at the turret from relative safety. Killing Symmetra turrets is a little harder with Junkrat, as they generally aren't on ground level, but if you have a tank or healer with you, it is a bit easier to clear out rooms.

Another person who is pretty good is S76. He has pretty solid mid range damage, and if he has a tank, he can usually pick off a Torb turret with a helpful rocket after shooting it a bit. He also can drop a health pack for himself to help tank it if he is alone.

Comment: On Volksaya specifically, where would you recommend the Junkrat flanks from to hit the turret? it's a pretty wide range, annoyingly. I can hop into a custom game and printscreen the point with the areas I'm referring to if that'd help?

Comment: @KizTrap, yea if you can show me where on the map you are having trouble taking out turrets, I can try and give you a suggestion on where to flank from.

Comment: Added the image. The only place I can think of is flanking from above the stairs on A, but getting in there (relatively) unseen is tricky when they're guarding the gate, and Symmetra can use turrets as sentries to alert for flankers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Junkrat can bomb jump the gap behind the building where you are standing. He can then launch bombs down onto the point. See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269432/which-heroes-can-clear-this-jump-on-volskaya-industries)

Comment: He doesn't have a good vantage point for the turret though- it's really hard to arc them from safety and get them as far as the red diamond. The whole composition is a notorious one for 'pubstomping', it'd be nice if there was a way to counter it while still bearing 3 silent randoms.

Comment: @KizTrap yea, that one is a bit difficult. It is where i setup my turret a lot. Though if you can get a tank and support with you, and you can make it around the side of the building where you marked B, you can poke from the corner of the building

Comment: So 3 person co-ordination may be able to be break through it? Guess I'll have to get my friends to work more in line with me :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43227/discussion-between-dragonrage-and-kiztrap).